# Console.Log confusion of output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to resolve an error I am having with rendering my show.js after new props are added to a graph. Currently, I logged this.props.notes to see what is undefined but I am not understanding what the 1 that was logged is.I am not sure why graph is undefined if it is present as I am looking for graph.id in notes and questions.

```js
Console.Log
(2) [{…}, undefined]
0:
content: "test"
graph:
id: 3
info_url: "https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/69/wr/mm6915e3.htm"
name: "Rates of Hospitalization for COVID-19"
screenshot_url: "https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/69/wr/social-media/mm6915e3_HospitalizationsCOVID19_IMAGE_08April20_1200x675-medium.jpg"
__proto__: Object
id: 27
__proto__: Object
1: undefined
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

```js
Show.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'graph' of undefined
    at Show.js:27
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Show.render (Show.js:27)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17160)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17110)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18620)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11072)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21893)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:806)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:4168)

index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <Show> component:
    in Show (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:29)
    in div (at App.js:24)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (at App.js:23)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:22)
    in App (at src/index.js:23)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:22)
```

```js
Show.js
// built-in(lifecycle) methods imported here
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// import components from local 
import Graph from '../components/Graph'
import Notes from '../components/Notes'
import Questions from '../components/Questions'

//imbrl allows us to enable routing by updating url and rendering needed component listed in routeer
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

//bootstrap WIP
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'

// access state from redux store
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Show extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.notes)
    // variables for objects
    const graph = this.props.graphs.find(graph => { return graph.id === parseInt(this.props.match.params.id)})
    const notes = this.props.notes.filter(note => note.graph.id === graph.id)
    const questions = this.props.questions.filter(question => question.graph.id === graph.id)


    // if graph exists it loads all corresponding notes and questions with it
    if (graph) {

        return (
            <Row>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <Notes graph={graph} notes={notes} />
                </Col>

                <Col md={6} >
                    <Card>
                        <Graph graph={graph}/>
                    </Card>

                    <NavLink
                    to={`/graphs/${graph.id}/interact`}>
                        <Button>Interact</Button>
                    </NavLink>
                </Col>


                <Col md={3}>
                    <Questions graph={graph} questions={questions} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavLink
                style={{marginRight: '10px'}}
                to="/">
                <Button variant="dark" size="lg" block>Add Data to get started</Button>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
         )
        }
    }
}


// this will need access to the objects
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        graphs: state.graphs,
        notes: state.notes,
        questions: state.questions
    }
}


export default connect (mapStateToProps)(Show)
```

Comment: Your error messages are in images, which means they can't be searched by people who have the same issue as you in the future. Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your errors in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Okay I will edit and add my error to the question.

Answer (score 0):

One of elements in notes array is `undefined`, so you are getting exceotion because you are trying to access graph key from `undefined` object. You can check whether graph is not undefined in filter conditon.

```
const notes = this.props.notes.filter(
  note => note.graph !== undefined && note.graph.id === graph.id
);
```

Also, check source of `notes` state and fix `undefined` notes state.